# Microsoft Graph - Filtering users by X500 proxyAddress

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Is it possible to query for users, filtered by an X500 proxy address?

Using the following query which filters by an SMTP address, I can return all of my proxy addresses:

```
/v1.0/users/?$filter=proxyAddresses/any(x:x eq 'smtp:me@here.com')&$select=proxyAddresses
```

However, if I take one of the X500 addresses that was returned in the above query and try and filter by that:

```
/v1.0/users/?$filter=proxyAddresses/any(x:x eq 'x500:/o=ExchangeLabs/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (blahblah)/cn=Recipients/cn=trimmed')&$select=proxyAddresses
```

then I get a 400:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Request_UnsupportedQuery",
    "message": "Unsupported or invalid query filter clause specified for property 'proxyAddresses' of resource 'User'.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "adcdefg",
      "date": "2019-01-01T01:01:01"
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried URL encoding the address, and also tried with and without the "X500:" scheme.

Is filtering by X500 address supported?

Comment: Thanks Mark. Support call opened with MSFT, I'll provide an official answer when I get one

Comment: @MarcLaFleur Also, interesting that LisaJ's second query below uses parenthesis and seems to work fine. I can see my organization in the address is "exchangelabs", not 100% sure, but I'd guess this is used for cloud-homed mailboxes - so maybe the issue is only with those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dan Kershaw answered - this does seem to be a hard coded limit of 120 characters in the email address being filtered on.

A simple workaround is to trim the email address (including the scheme - "x500:" or "smtp:") to 120 characters, and search using a "startswith":

```
/v1.0/users/?$filter=proxyAddresses/any(x:startswith(x, 'x500:/o=ExchangeLabs/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (blahblah)/cn=Recipients/cn=trimmed'))&$select=proxyAddresses
```

This may return more than one match, so its then a case of looking through each returned user, and looking at their "proxyAddresses" collection to see which matches the original untrimmed email address that's being searched for.

Comment: Funny that - I was just coming back to this thread to suggest exactly the same thing on using a startswith clause.  Kudos to you Paul, and thanks for sharing with the community!  I will still be filing a bug for this issue too.

Comment: Cheers @DanKershaw-MSFT - glad there'll be a bug open on it as it's the sort of issue that could easily be missed in testing, and then only appear sporadically in a prod environment

Answer (score 2):

I am able to use X500 addresses as filters without any modification to the address from a [clone of GraphExplorer](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-explorer.git). The following queries both return the correct user record

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/?$filter=proxyAddresses/any(x:x eq 'x500:/o=Company Exchange/ou=First Administrative Group/cn=Recipients/cn=UIDHere')&$select=proxyAddresses
```

and

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/?$filter=proxyAddresses/any(x:x eq 'X500:/o=Company Exchange/ou=External (FYDIBOHF25SPDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=z804261192zc46c4az4f6032z322540z')&$select=proxyAddresses
```

Comment: Thanks - good to know it's supported. I still can't get it working here, and i'm struggling to see any differences between your query and mine. One for MSFT support then, I guess

Answer (score 2):

Like Lisa - this is not about parenthesis.  I have Any lambda queries on proxyAddresses using X500 addresses containing parentheses that working just fine in Graph Explorer.

I suspect that the issue is actually size of the search string.  I repro the error if the size of the search string is greater than 120 characters.

I'm following up with the engineering team.

In the meantime Paul, as a workaround (and excuse my lack of X500 knowledge), is there a way to query using the shortest X500 string?

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks Dan. I'm also lacking in X500 knowledge, so not sure if it's possible to shorten that string. My solution is an Outlook integration - I'm pulling the X500 address using the client-side Outlook API, so i'm at Outlook's mercy in terms of the address I'm given. It's potentially possible to resolve the X500 to e.g. an smtp address using the Outlook API, but this adds a fair amount of complication (e.g. works differently in offline mode) so I'd much rather just hand off what I'm given to Graph

Comment: I'll try and respond once I hear back from the engineering team, and see whether a fix is possible.  Do you only get one X500 back?  If you get multiple back from Outlook, could you choose the shortest?

Comment: OK, thanks Dan. I only get one address back unfortunately

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, Dan. I've found a simple workaround - see the accepted answer. From what I can make out, Azure AD has a limit of 133 characters for proxyAddresses, so it would be great if the limit on the filter parameter could be increased accordingly

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that this is still an issue as of today's date.

I'm actually using the AzureAD PowerShell cmdlets, which leverage the Graph API.

I couldn't figure out why my query was failing until I found this thread, so thanks for that.

I was getting essentially the same error message in PowerShell:
"Unsupported or invalid query filter clause specified for property 'proxyAddresses' of resource 'Group'."

When I took a substring of the first 120 characters and ran a startsWith, it worked fine.

It's a shame that this issue still hasn't been resolved.